# How to disable default BotBuilder logs

Tags: node.js, logging, botframework

by default the [botbuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder) logs all sorts of logs using `session.log` or chatconnector logger.

It is possible to partially disable within the lifecycle event:

`botbuilder: (session, next) => session.logger.log = () => {} // disable bot-builder logs`

But that is dirty.

Any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use:

```
botbuilder: (session, next) => {
        session.logger.isEnabled = false;
        next();
    }
```